# How do I translate 手指往前一点，纸牌化作黑色的线，纤拉而过，犹如一线江潮倾轧?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm trying to understand this sentence, but it doesn't really make much sense to me.
I've tried translating (using google translate) it but it still doesn't make much sense to me. Could someone correctly translate this sentence.

Sentence with context:

轻轻画个圈。(I understand)

悬浮在她周身的一张张纸牌，骤然高速旋转起来。(I understand)

手指往前一点，纸牌化作黑色的线，纤拉而过，犹如一线江潮倾轧。(This is the sentence)

My understanding of the sentence:

The finger moved, the black cards turned into black fiber, the fiber went around and through, like a river tide rolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"倾轧" is not a standard word, and I think it is a word coined composed by putting 倾 and 轧 together by the author itself.倾轧 in the dictionary is defined as "engage in internal strife“, but in context you give, obviously it is not.

In my understanding, the component "倾” here means to incline toward, 轧" here means to cover over, so 江潮倾轧 means tides of the river incline toward and cover over.

this is my translation:

The finger moved forward a little, the black cards turned into a black rope, the rope that was pulled toward went through as if a river tide of the river incline toward and cover over.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by pulled towards went through, because isn't pulled towards and went through a contradiction.

Comment: combining with context,”纤拉而过”  here indicates that someone drags the rope and leads it  going through; 用中文描述就是 “绳子被人拉着向前穿过”

Comment: Oh I understand, so it means pull forwards and went through, I get it now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What is this, the description of a magic trick?? Make the card disappear?

Here I would equate 倾轧 with 涌动, like the surging of a tidal wave at an equinox, bubbling and boiling as it passes. If you flip one end of a piece of string, a wave runs down it.

一线: (in the) front line,

手指往前一点，
Fingers pointing forwards a little,
纸牌化作黑色的线，
the cards become black threads,
纤拉而过，
a gentle flip and they're gone,
犹如一线江潮倾轧。
like the surging wave of a river tide.

Comment: It's from a fantasy novel I'm currently reading, 这个梦境很有趣, I don't know how I would explain it, but its roughly that the girl would be like "Twisted fate" from LoL killing monsters with her cards, as in the next sentence the monster's head would come off.